# Javascript unit-testing for Rails 3.1 and asset pipeline

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, asset-pipeline

I'm looking for the easiest possible Javascript unit-testing system for Rails 3.1 that is specifically capable of working with the asset pipeline out of the box.

I've tried various incarnations of the jasmine gem, including jasmine-rice, headless-jasmine-webkit.  Jasmine gem does not appear to work with rails 3.1 out of the box, requiring tweaking of various config files.  Jasmine-rice and headless-jasmine-webkit both have complicated dependencies and require more tweaking of the config file.

Any suggestions?  Ideally I would need to include HTML/HAML fixtures, and be headless, but at this point I would be happy with anything that allows me to test my javascript with minimal configuration.

Comment: any luck with this? I am having the same issues

Comment: Unfortunately not.  Attended a moderate-sized Ruby conference a few weeks ago, the general consensus was to test with Selenium...or not at all.  I was forced to abandon capybara-webkit in favor of selenium after one too many strange bugs, no good out-of-the-box solution I know of.

Answer (score 1):

Jasmine is the best solution. We're using this to test all our JS code. It works beautifully with CoffeeScript as well.

But don't install the version of RubyGems.org (it's not been updated in a while), just get the latest from github, e.g. add to your `Gemfile`:

```
group :test do    
  gem 'jasmine', :git => 'https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine-gem.git'
end
```

Then you can run `rake jasmine` and go to `http://localhost:8888` to run your tests. Headless webkit also works.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for something that would allow me to unit and functional test my javascript within MS Test in visual studio.  Took me forever but I found [WatiN](http://watin.org/).  What WatiN will do is open internet explorer and run a web page.  If you run your IDE as an administrator you can even open local HTML files.

I am currently using it with Visual Studio to run functional and unit tests on all my javascript.  I think that so far this is the best solution out of the box for running javascript functional tests from your IDE.  For my unit tests I used YUI test, but since you are opening a browser and running javascript within the browser you can use any javascript test framework you want (like qUnit).

Answer (score 0):

I've been using QUnit, a simple yet effective Unit Testing library built on jQuery:

http://docs.jquery.com/QUnit

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully late is better than never... I just wrote a small library that should solve your problem:
https://github.com/proxv/qlive-rails

It injects qunit and your qunit tests into live server responses. It also lets you set state server-side in advance of the tests (like logging in a user and setting content for the page) to reduce client-side mocking.

If you are using rspec, there's also an add-on that will run the qunit tests headlessly along with your other rspec examples.